# How to Solve Equation Involving Subject of Formular In Matlab

Tags: matlab, linear-algebra, equation-solving

I have an expression that I want to evaluate in MATLAB. This is a part of automatic control computation and each time I need to compute a theta(t) value which has a relationship as shown below:

[image: MATLAB Evaluation Figure]

My objective is to evaluate the left-hand side expression in the red box against row-wise equivalent right-side and obtain the actual value for t.

I will appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the Transformation Matrix is represented by T, therefore:
    x = T(1,4)==V(1);
    y = T(2,4)==V(2);
    z = T(3,4)==V(3);
Apply linear equation solver: a=solve(x,t).
To obtain the actual value of t, eval(a).